# Save and Play Different AVAudioRecorder Files

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to play around with `AVAudioRecorder` and what I am trying to do now is to record and play on different views.

Here is how it goes. I have 20 views(or pages because I am preparing for a book app) in each page you can record and automatically saves the file when you stop, then, play it only on that page. When you go to other pages you can record again another, and when you go back to the previous pages your previous recordings are still playable.

How can I do that? I've tried giving the files different names and play it using the `AVAudioPlayer` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of multiple filenames is one of the easiest way to address this need.  I use multiple files to store audio data for one of my apps.  In my case I preload the data from the file into memory then alloc a new AVAudioPlayer object and init it with the data:

self.msg = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePathAsString];
self.player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.msg error:&err] autorelease];
...
[self.msg release];

To record a given audio clip again simply save the recorded data over any existing data in a file associated with the view in question and your playback automatically gets the new audio when the code above executes.